# Assigning new variables in classes that extend from an abstract class

Tags: java, abstract-class, abstract

I have an abstract class called items and would like to create two classes called Appliance and SmallHwItem that extend items class. In my items abstract class I have variables that will be constant for both classes that extend it, but would like to add different variables to the items constructor within the appliance and smallhwitem classes. For example: Id like to include string variables "Type", "Brand", and "Category" in the appliance class. Sorry I am new to abstract classes and would appreciate any feedback. Here are my two classes below.

Items.java:

```
package hardwarestore;

    import java.io.Serializable;

    /**
     * This class is a very simple representation of a hardware item. There are only getter
     * methods and no setter methods and as a result an item cannot be mutated once
     * initialized. An item object can also call the two override methods
     * <CODE>toString()</CODE> and <CODE>equals()</CODE>
     *
     */
    public abstract class Item implements Serializable {

        /**
         * 
         */
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
        private final String idNumber;
        private final String name;
        private int quantity;
        private final float price;


        public Item(String idNumber, String name, String category, int quantity, float price) {
            this.idNumber = idNumber;
            this.name = name;
            this.quantity = quantity;
            this.price = price;
        }

        /**
         * This method returns the item's tracking number.
         *
         * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that is the ID number of the item.
         */
        public String getIdNumber() {
            return idNumber;
        }

        /**
         * This method returns the item's name.
         *
         * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that is the item's name.
         */
        public String getName() {
            return name;
        }



        /**
         * This method returns the item's quantity.
         *
         * @return an <b><CODE>int</CODE></b> that is the item's weight
         */
        public int getQuantity() {
            return quantity;
        }

        /**
         * This method set the item's quantity.
         *
         *  @param quantity a <b><CODE>int</CODE></b> that represents the quantity
         */
        public void setQuantity(int quantity) {
            this.quantity= quantity;
        }

        /**
         * This method returns the item's price.
         *
         * @return a <b><CODE>float</CODE></b> that is the item's price
         */
        public float getPrice() {
            return price;
        }

        /**
         * This abstract method returns the item's fields as a string representation.
         *
         * @return a <b><CODE>String</CODE></b> that lists the fields of the item
         * object delineated by a space and in the same order as the constructor
         */
        public abstract String getFormattedInfo();

        /**
         * This method provides a way to compare two item objects.
         *
         * @param c a <b><CODE>Item</CODE></b> object that is used to compare to
         * <b><CODE>this</CODE></b> item. Two orders are equal if their ID is the
         * same.
         * @return the <CODE>boolean</CODE> value of the comparison.
         */
        public boolean equals(Item c) {
            return c.getIdNumber().equals(this.idNumber);
        }

    }
```

Appliance.java:

```
package hardwarestore;

public class Appliance extends Item{

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private final String brand;
    private final String type;
    private final String category;


    public Appliance(String idNumber, String name, String brand, String type, String category, int quantity, float price) { 

        super(idNumber, name, brand, quantity, price);

    }



    public String getFormattedInfo() { 

        return null;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just set the fields in your concrete class `Appliance` with `this`

```
public Appliance(String idNumber, String name, String brand, String type, String category, int quantity, float price) { 

    super(idNumber, name, category, quantity, price);
    this.brand = brand;
    this.type = type;
    this.category = category;
}
```

By the way, you're not using category in the abstract constructor.